# Tensorflow Keras Graph Error ( Graph Execution Error)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, compiler-errors

I know a similar question has been asked before but I'm literally following a tutorial and getting an error. I've looked through all the possible answers and I still don't get how to correct this. This is the code :

I tried following the tutorial multiple times and looked all over before posting this question but it just doesn't seem to work. At best I narrowed it down to something to do with the shape or the labels but I can't figure out how to solve it. I appreciate the help

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import boston_housing
from tensorflow.keras import layers

SEED_VALUE = 65

# fix the seed to make it deterministic.
np.random.seed(SEED_VALUE)
tf.random.set_seed(SEED_VALUE)

# Load the boston housing dataset

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test ) = boston_housing.load_data()
print(X_train.shape)
print("\n")
print("Input features: ", X_train[0])
print("\n")
print("Input features: ", y_train[0])

boston_features = {
'Average Number of Rooms': 5,
}

X_train_1d = X_train[:, boston_features['Average Number of Rooms']]
print(X_train_1d.shape)

X_test_1d = X_test[:, boston_features['Average Number of Rooms']]

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))

plt.xlabel('Average number of rooms')
plt.ylabel('Median Price [$K]')
plt.grid("on")
plt.scatter(X_train_1d[:], y_train, color='green', alpha=0.5);

model = Sequential()

# Define model consisting of a single neuron.
model.add(Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1,)))

# Display a summary of the model architechture. 
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=.005), loss='mse')

history = model.fit(X_train_1d, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=101, validation_split=0.3)`
```

And I get the following error:

```
Epoch 1/101
2023-01-21 12:03:45.701983: I        tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
2023-01-21 12:03:45.757923: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed     at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x281ae11b0
2023-01-21 12:03:45.757952: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed     at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x281ae11b0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 1
----> 1 history = model.fit(X_train_1d, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=101,      validation_split=0.3)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     55   if name is not None:

NotFoundError: Graph execution error:
```

Comment: The traceback does not end at "Graph execution error", you need to include it completely.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out I will copy it here

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine when I tried replicating the same code in Google Colab using the default available version of `python 3.8.10` and `TensorFlow 2.9.2` as well as tried in local machine in conda environment using `Python 3.10` and `TensorFlow 2.9`. (Attaching the working code [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/5821d294f43cd933bf9dcf8b62751556/75192950.ipynb) here for your reference)

Please check below the output of your mentioned code:

[image]